# Cost to alter the transmission system

Tags: automatic-transmission, manual-transmission

How expensive would it be to replace a manual transmission system to an automatic?

Answer (score 6):

In most cars it's a major operation and quite expensive.  There's usually body and mount modifications that need to be made.  You'll need the new trans and all the controls.  Some cars have a different ECU and wiring harness for each transmission.  Possibly vacuum system modifications.  Sometimes it even requires changing out drive/halfshafts, etc.  What make/model do you want to do this too, and how much of the work can you do yourself?

Comment: I looked into this years ago for an A>M conversion. Unless you have a complete donor car to cover all the things Brian said, forget it. That said, the other car can be totaled and you can scrap the metal afterwards.